# Can anyone tell me why my d3 bar chart isn't showing up?

Tags: node.js, angular, d3.js, charts

The below code is supposed to render a graph, but for some reason is not.  I am not sure why, anyone?  I installed d3 and have "@types/d3": "^5.0.1" in my package.json, as well as "d3": "^5.7.0".

```
//in component.html
<mat-card>
<h2>Amount Total By Service</h2>
<mat-card-content>
    D3.js graph here
    <svg width='500' height='200'></svg>
</mat-card-content>  
</mat-card>  



//in component.ts
import  * as d3 from 'd3';


constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
 //this.http.get('/api/home', {}).subscribe(res => { 
 this.invoices = res;   console.log(res), (err) => {console.log(err)}})
 this.invoices = this.http.get('/api/home/' + localStorage.getItem('username'),  {});
 this.buildChart();
 }

buildChart(){
var data = [80, 120, 60, 150,200];
var svgWidth = 500, svgHeight = 200, barPadding = 5;
var barWidth = (svgWidth / data.length);

var svg = d3.select('svg')
      .attr('width', svgWidth)
      .attr('height', svgHeight);
svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr("y", function(d){
        return svgHeight - d
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d
      })
      .attr("width", barWidth - barPadding)
      .attr("fill", "red")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i){
        var translate = [barWidth * i, 0];
        return "translate(" + translate + ")";
      })
}
```

I just found out that the flag didn't have anything to do with it.  The button needs to be pressed twice to render the chart.  The error is at 'start of buildchart'
        
         `//console.log first click
         start of buildchart
         home.component.ts:71 
         Selection {
         _groups: Array(1),
         _parents: Array(1)
         }
         _groups: Array(1)
         0: [null]
         length: 1
         __proto__: Array(0)
         _parents: [html]
         __proto__: Object
         //console.log second click
         home.component.ts:47 
         start of buildchart
         home.component.ts:71 
         Selection {
         _groups: Array(1), 
         _parents: Array(1)
         }
         _groups: Array(1)
         0: [svg]
         length: 1
         __proto__: Array(0)
         _parents: [html]
         __proto__: Object`

Answer (score 0):

Testing only your d3 code seems to be working. See snippet below.
Seems like you're using the code inside an Angular component, be aware of the component lifecycle. Look at this example on codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/epLNVZ

```js
function buildChart() {
var data = [80, 120, 60, 150,200];
var svgWidth = 500, svgHeight = 200, barPadding = 5;
var barWidth = (svgWidth / data.length);

var svg = d3.select('svg')
      .attr('width', svgWidth)
      .attr('height', svgHeight);
svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr("y", function(d){
        return svgHeight - d
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d
      })
      .attr("width", barWidth - barPadding)
      .attr("fill", "red")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i){
        var translate = [barWidth * i, 0];
        return "translate(" + translate + ")";
      })
}
buildChart();
```

```html
<svg width='500' height='200'></svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at.  I looked at the codepen, but am a bit foggy with lifecycles I guess.

Comment: Basically is the timeout before rendering d3, I'm not familiar with Angular, but other framework react/vue. They all have lifecycles, and you can't select elements that are not yet rendered. The lifecycles then when the framework render on DOM and then you can use d3.select. The timeout on codepen, seems like a hack, on React/Vue you have methods such as mounted, created, in those events you're ready to select elements.

Comment: Even when I attached the buildChart to a button to build the chart, it still doesn't render.

Comment: Could you setup a codepen/snippet reproducing your problem?

Comment: I did attempt to, but codepen is all new to me, and I didn't want to have to take a tutorial for it.  It turns out that the issue was not with the graph, it was with the buildChart function not getting called when my flag changed.  Not sure why still, but I kicked out the flag and it renders now.  I appreciate your willingness to help though @cal_br_mar!!

Comment: I just found out that the flag didn't have anything to do with it.  The button needs to be pressed twice to render the chart.  
        start of buildchart
        home.component.ts:71 
        Selection {
        _groups: Array(1), _parents: Array(1)}_groups: Array(1)0: [null]length: 1__proto__: Array(0)_parents: [html]__proto__: Object
home.component.ts:47 start of buildchart
home.component.ts:71 Selection {_groups: Array(1), _parents: Array(1)}_groups: Array(1)0: [svg]length: 1__proto__: Array(0)_parents: [html]__proto__: Object